# Some Moto 360 doesn't load rounded layout

Tags: android, wear-os

i wrote an application that run on round and square watches, with two layouts and a watchViewStub.
Since the moto 360 is sold over Europe i have many reports that Moto 360 doesn't load the rounded layout. With emulator, i can't reproduce this behavior even if i change locale as explain here : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#testing
So i guess it's my code ...

Here's is how i've implemented it :

```
<android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/watch_view_stub"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:rectLayout="@layout/rect_activity_camera"
app:roundLayout="@layout/round_activity_camera">
```

Then in a fragment i inflate the WatchViewStub

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) getView().findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            ...
        } 
    }
```

The fragment is used in a FragmentViewPager/FragmentGridPagerAdapter.
Until i get a Moto 360, any ideas on how i can debug this ?

**Edit**

WatchViewStub sample in Wear Sdk has two different behavior depends on language settings so i fill this issue : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77642

**Important**

This issue is discussed on different posts. to avoid repeating the updated information only the issue on google code will be updated, and i'll complete this posts once the issue will be solved :
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77642

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with inflating layouts that are caused by not correctly using WatchViewStub. I don't see enough code above to know exactly, but one common issue is when you register a listener for watch insets:

```
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(new View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
        @Override
        public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(View view, WindowInsets windowInsets) {
            // Need to also call the original insets since we have overridden the original                                                  
            // https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener.html                                   
            stub.onApplyWindowInsets(windowInsets);

            return windowInsets;
        }
    });
```

I see cases where people forget to return the windowInsets, or forget to call stub.onApplyWindowInsets(). This has the effect of giving a square layout instead of a round layout.

Other issues are caused by forgetting to put the same XML elements into the round.xml as the square.xml.

What is the error message you are getting in adb logcat?

Comment: thanks wayne for help. I've just get a french Moto 360 with KGW42R and i run the sample WatchViewStub and it says "your screen is rectangular". I reset the device to English (US) and then it founds a round screen. I'll fill a bug. Once again thanks

Comment: Can you please post a link to the bug? So you are saying that just changing the locale of the device makes the bug occur?

Comment: I've updated my post with the link to the issue. If i find a workaround i'll update this post.

Comment: I will look into this problem internally for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have some information for you about this bug.

The problem is triggered by the watch switching languages when pairing with a phone after a factory reset. You can avoid the issue by selecting the same language on the wearable as you are using on the phone, so that no change occurs afterwards when the devices are paired.

Instructions to fix the problem:

1. Factory reset the Moto 360.
2. When the wearable restarts, it will ask what language you would like to use. Select the same language that you are using on the phone (do not select the default of English)
3. On the phone, start the Android Wear companion app, and select from the overflow menu the option "Pair with a new wearable".
4. Pair the phone with the Moto 360.

Comment: unfortunately this workaround doesn't work in time. After a restart the watch load the square layout again.